# python strptime from UTC string to datetime regex re.sub

Tags: python, regex

im using the following that works awesome for converting a UTC string to date times -- except when the milliseconds are LONGER than 6 digits. than it blows. urgh*&^*&

```
format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
if '.' in value:
    format = format + '.%f'
if value.endswith('Z'):
    format = format + 'Z'        
return datetime.strptime(value, format)
```

here is the stacktrace

```
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '2013-07-19T13:02:53.8241899Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
```

whats a method to restrict the milliseconds to 6 digits in length. ive used using `'{:%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.6%f}'.format(  datetime )` but that helps nonce/

so trying re.sub( ) to limit the decimals (if any) following the '.'character in the provided string. but am not very regex savvy.

im using python 2.6.* on the machine.

Comment: Do you really need to have 6 digits of miliseconds? :O

Comment: This example snippet might be better if the code itself included values for `sz` and `value`.

Comment: to generate correct string, you could use `datetime.utcnow().isoformat()+'Z'`. It looks like [`rfc3339`](http://tools.ietf.org/search/rfc3339#section-5.6) doesn't limit number of digits after decimal point. So if input string ends with `Z` then it is a valid rfc3339 date in your case.

Comment: nope i dont need 6 digits. that date is not within my control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `.partition()` method to parse the string:

```
from datetime import datetime

sz = '2013-07-19T13:02:53.8241899Z' # utc time in rfc3339 format (without offset)

sz = sz.rstrip('Z') # remove ending 'Z' if present
timestr, _, digits = sz.partition('.')
utc_dt = datetime.strptime(timestr, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
if digits:
   microseconds = int(digits, 10) * 10**(6 - len(digits))
   utc_dt = utc_dt.replace(microsecond=int(microseconds + .5))
```

If you want to use `re.sub` and don't mind truncating the microseconds:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

sz = '2013-07-19T13:02:53.8241899Z'
if '.' in sz: 
   sz = re.sub(r'(\.\d{,6})\d*Z?$', r'\1Z', sz) # truncate to 6 digits +Z
else: # no fractions
   sz = sz.rstrip('Z') + '.0Z'

utc_dt = datetime.strptime(sz, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
```

Comment: thnx. ill give yours a shot if the re.sub method proves too slow. regards.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a job for [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2).

```
$ pip install python-dateutil
$ python
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> d = dateutil.parser.parse('2013-07-19T13:02:53.8241899Z')
>>> print d
2013-07-19 13:02:53.824189+00:00
```

Comment: `dateutil` truncates microseconds instead of rounding them. Anyway it is an overkill to use it for the rfc3339 format that ends with `Z`. A [simple `.partition('.')` would work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20534752/4279)

Comment: thnx. truncate is ok. may give it a shot in the longer run. regards.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to do it with `re.sub`, here's a short example of one way to do that.

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

value = '2013-07-19T13:02:53.8241899Z'

regex = r"(\d{6,}\d+)"

if re.search(regex, value):
    repl = lambda x: x.group(0)[:6]
    value = re.sub(pattern=regex, repl=repl, string=value)

format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
if '.' in value:
    format = format + '.%f'
if value.endswith('Z'):
    format = format + 'Z'        
print datetime.strptime(value, format)
```